# C# - Accessing a variable inside and outside a class

Tags: c#

I wanted to access an instance variable from inside and outside of a class. I created a class like this:

```
public class Test {
    public int a = 0;
    a = 3;
}
```

I can't access variable a from inside the class. But, I can access a from outside of the class:

```
Test abc = new Test()
abc.a = 3;
```

It works. Is there any way I can access the variable from inside the class and outside the class?

Comment: You may need to use methods inside class. So, when you instantiate a class the object contains both property and methods. Now, methods can access the variable of the instantiated object internally. Anyways, Why do you want to access the object (instantiated) variable inside class?

Comment: Code must be inside *methods*. That's invalid C# code. A good book might be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: `a` is not a variable, it's a member field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `a = 3;` code into a method or constructor.

```
public class Test {
    public int a = 0;

    public Test(){
        a = 3;
    }

    public int Plus2() {
        return a + 2;
    }
}
```